# How to access Wikipedia using Node.js

Tags: node.js, wikipedia

I am looking into the simplest way to integrate Wikipedia into a node.js app.
The requirements are to be able to search for entries and find entities in each entry.

Any known existing libs/methods for that?

Thanks

Comment: You should probably say what you want to do with it. Simply scraping and displaying the HTML from Wikipedia.org should be a simple matter.

Answer (score 2):

There's a newly available open source parser for wiki text (http://sweble.org/) that might be useful to you if you roll your own solution. Of course that would require you downloading the wikipedia data dump, parsing, and storing entities in a db.

You could also look at dbpedia (http://dbpedia.org/About), though that would require integrating the rdf stack into your app (either running a local rdf repository or communicating with the often flaky online version via sparql).

One easy approach is to use a search engine api and restrict to site:wikipedia.org - e.g:

http://www.google.com/search?q=node.js+site%3Awikipedia.org

I've found that can work really well.

Answer (score 0):

Spider for scraping using jquery is fantastic:

https://github.com/mikeal/spider

Mikeal is the man

Presumably you'd be using this for a side (personal) project though. Not sure how kosher it is to run wild on wikipedia with a scraper.